# usemin using wrong directory for input asset files

Tags: javascript, laravel, gruntjs, laravel-blade, grunt-usemin

I'm attempting to get a gruntfile working to concatenate / uglify javascript files in a Laravel application.  All of my tasks work in isolation, but for whatever reason the paths to my input javascript files are not being set correctly.

Here's an example of one of my blade templates:

```
@section('scripts')
<!-- build:js /js/min/page.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scrollIt.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.omniwindow.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/isotope.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
@stop
```

Here's my useminPrepare / usemin task definitions:

```
useminPrepare: {
    html: 'app/views/**/*.blade.php',
    options: {
        dest: 'app/views/dist'
    }
},
usemin: {
    options: {
        assetDirs: [ 'public/js' ]
    },
    html: [ 'app/views/dist/**/*.blade.php' ]
},
```

I have no defined `uglify` task, I'm just relying on the one that usemin will generate.

All templates are making it into the 'app/views/dist' directory correctly, with the correct replacement (in the example above, there's a single javascript file at `public/js/min/page.min.js` being included in the template).  During processing, I noticed output:

```
$ grunt build
Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Going through {list of templates} to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

  concat:
  { generated: 
   { files: 
      [ { dest: '.tmp/concat/js/min/page.min.js',
          src: 
           [ 'app/views/course/js/scrollIt.min.js',
             'app/views/course/js/jquery.omniwindow.js',
             'app/views/course/js/isotope.min.js' ] },
        ] } }

  uglify:
  { generated: 
   { files: 
      [ { dest: 'app/views/dist/js/min/page.min.js',
          src: [ '.tmp/concat/js/min/page.min.js' ] },
        ] } }

  cssmin:
  {}
```

As you can see above, it is looking for my javascript files in `app/views/course/js` directory, which is incorrect.  Why is this?  I thought specifying `assetDirs: ['public/js']` in my usemin task would tell grunt where to find those files.  I have tried changing the script references to look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../public/js/scrollIt.min.js"></script>
```

And this causes a successful build, but breaks my local development so its definitely not a solution.  Do I need to somehow override the `uglify:generated` task, and if so, how do I do it for multiple different templates with generated filenames?

If it's necessary, you can see the entirety of my Gruntfile.js [here](http://pastebin.com/TbBeQD33).  You can see from there I had to also add a new `copy` task for copying Javascript files from `app/views/dist/js/min` back over to `public/js/min`.  I'd also like to get rid of that, but if I can just get around this issue I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here actually turned out to be relatively simple, and was able to be gathered directly from the [usemin documentation](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#user-content-blocks) (as soon as I started to look hard enough):

> Blocks are expressed as:

```
<!-- build:<type>(alternate search path) <path> -->
... HTML Markup, list of script / link tags.
<!-- endbuild -->
```

In my case for working with Laravel, I needed to specify an alternate search path of `public/` and it wound up working just fine:

```
@section('scripts')
<!-- build:js(public/) /js/min/script.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script4.js"></script>
<!-- endbuid -->
@stop
```